The order of ObserverEvents and reactive parts in Rshiny changes when I run the app. How can I control the order of events?
I have a shiny app that runs a model and then calculates a table based on it. There is a button to run the model, which calls an observerEvent() and then the table is a reactive(). I want to keep it reactive. When I first open the app and press the button it:

makes the table and then
runs the model.

However, if I close the app (keeping R open) and reload the app it:

runs the model and then
makes the table.

If I close R and start again it goes back to the first one.
Below is an example based on the full app. I have got the console to print out the events as they run.
rm(list = ls())


library(shiny)
library(shinyvalidate)
library(shinyjs)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shinythemes)
library(DT)


ui <- fluidPage(
  shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
  theme = shinytheme("cerulean"),
  titlePanel(title = "Test", 
             windowTitle = "Test"),
  sidebarLayout(mainPanel = mainPanel(tags$head(
    tags$style(
      HTML("body {
                              font-family: 'Open Sans';
                              font-size: 14px;
                              line-height: 1.42857143;
                                               }",
           ".shiny-notification {
              height: 100px;
              width: 400px;
              position:fixed;
              opacity:1;
              top: calc(50% - 50px);;
              left: calc(50% - 200px);;
            }
           "))), width = 7, 
    # Main panel is a series of tabs for each input
    tabsetPanel(type = "tabs", id = "tabs",
                tabPanel(title = "SSB",
                         fluidRow(plotOutput(outputId = "ensPlot")),
                         fluidRow(column(width = 6, DTOutput(outputId = "ensTab")),
                                  column(width = 3, DTOutput(outputId = "blimINPUT")),
                                  column(width = 3, imageOutput(outputId = "legend"))))
    )
    
  ),
  

  sidebarPanel = sidebarPanel(width = 5,
                              tags$head(tags$style(HTML("body{font-family: 'Open Sans'}")))
                              ,
                              
                              #fluidRow(
                              #  column(width = 3, h4("Species")),
                              #  column(width = 5, h4("Fs")),
                              #  column(width = 4, h4("Reference Point"))
                              #),
                              
                              
                              column(width = 3,numericInput(inputId = "san_F_reference", value = 294000, min = 0, 
                                                            max = Inf, step = 1, label = NULL)),
                              fluidRow(column(3, actionButton(inputId = "runModel", label = "Run Model")),
                                       )
  )
  ))

server <- function(input, output, session){
  blimListen <- reactive({
    
    blim_out <- c(input$san_F_reference)
    
    return(blim_out)
    
  })
  
  
  observeEvent(input$reference, {
   print("dunno")
   updateNumericInput(session,inputId = "san_F_reference", value = 294000)})
  
  
  observeEvent(blimListen(), {
    print("runBlimList")})
  
  observeEvent(input$runModel, {
    # first: just check if the user has already saved a model
    print("run model")
  })
  ensTabReact <- reactive({
    req(input$runModel) # waits for a model to run, then updates the table
    #browser()
    #print(input$runModel)
    print("run table")
    return(matrix(1,2,2))
  })
  output$ensTab <- renderDT({
    print("run ensTab")
    ensTabReact()
  })
}
shinyApp(ui,server)


When R opens and this is first run pressing the button outputs:
[1] "runBlimList"
[1] "run ensTab"
[1] "run ensTab"
[1] "run table"
[1] "run model"

whereas when the app is run again it becomes:
[1] "runBlimList"
[1] "run ensTab"
[1] "run model"
[1] "run ensTab"
[1] "run table"

Why does this happen? I want it to be the later.
I removed the line:
observeEvent(input$reference, {
   print("dunno")
   updateNumericInput(session,inputId = "san_F_reference", value = 294000)})

and the model was run before the table was created
[1] "runBlimList"
[1] "run ensTab"
[1] "run model"
[1] "run ensTab"
[1] "run table"

This ordering remains unchanged when rerunning the app.
I have added the print(dunno) line to see if this is ever run and it appears it does not.
I don't understand what this line is doing. In the full app I removed this part and it didn't fix the problem.
I also removed the line:
 observeEvent(blimListen(), {
    print("runBlimList")})

and this also fixed the problem, i.e.,
[1] "runBlimList"
[1] "run ensTab"
[1] "run model"
[1] "run ensTab"
[1] "run table"

This fixed the problem in the full app however there are things that happen in this event that are required.

I might have solved this with priority=1 in observeEvent(input$runModel,....
Still, not sure why the error occurred in the first place.

The issue is that both, the reactive and the observeEvent are triggered by the same input. You could implement e.g. a reactiveVal, which is populated in the observeEvent  to trigger the reactive to force the correct execution order.
